# Trying to call function in componentWillUnmount REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a music player, and when the user closes the app, for that Im running this in componentWillUnmount:

```
mounted = false;

componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    if (this.mounted) {
        AppState.addEventListener("change", this.hola);
        TrackPlayer.addEventListener("playback-track-changed", this.get_actual_track);
        TrackPlayer.addEventListener("playback-queue-ended", this.get_queue_option);
        this.init();
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
    TrackPlayer.pause().then(() => {
        TrackPlayer.destroy();
    })
}
```

it closes the app and destroys the player, but when i re open the app it throws me this error:

```
[Sun Dec 20 2020 13:27:55.491]  ERROR    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: You also have an AppState event listener. Also, maybe you could try unlistening before pausing and destroying TrackPlayer (since it seems like that's asynchronous and might take a while, after the component is unmounted. Unlistening first synchronously might help you get rid of post-unmount state changes)

Comment: nop, removing the eventlistener then pausing and destroying doesnt work either